# JSLint errors on 'new function(){...}' but why? If I want anonymous closures, is there a better method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, closures, jslint

I’m trying backbone and playing with the model concept – something I’ve implemented without a framework in the past. I’m also trying sublime text with the javascript linter turned on, and have noticed it hates “new” quite a bit.

```
var StandardMethod = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        console.log('init');
    }
});

var LintOk = Backbone.Model.extend((function(){
    this.initialize = function(){
        console.log('init');
    };
    return this;
})());

var LintHates = Backbone.Model.extend(new function(){
    this.initialize = function(){
        console.log('init');
    };
});
var sm = new StandardMethod();
var lo = new LintOk();
var lh = new LintHates();​
```

The LintOk method requires changes in 3 different places in order to create a closure-compatible function. So if I want some closure variables like:

```
var NowWithClosures = Backbone.Model.extend(new function(){
    var x = 1;
    this.initialize = function(){
        console.log('init');
    };
    this.AddOneToX = function(){
        x++;
    };
    this.getX = function() {
        return x;
    };
});

var nwc = new NowWithClosures();
nwc.AddOneToX();
console.log(nwc.getX());
```

I have to use this very verbose method in order to be lint-approved? Is there something I’m missing here? What’s the reasoning for this? I could "return this;" in all my model definitions but that seems silly, and not intuitive - the model definition might be more than one screen long and the "new" call would be at the top making it more obviously an anonymous constructor.

Comment: Why would you want to do this as every model you instantiate would share the same `x`. Also, in your `LintOK` snippet, `this` will be the global object.

Comment: There might be cases when I *want* the models to share the same x.

Comment: Excellent point about `this` being the global object in the `LintOk` version. The global object is obviously not what I want here!

Comment: Yes there's a better method: Use http://jsHint.com/ instead. It's very configurable, and has a setting to allow that. See `supernew` on the [options page](http://www.jshint.com/options/).

Comment: That 'new' keyword is sure 'super'! Thanks @am-not-i-am

Comment: Would you consider re-wording your question to remove references to backbone.js?  Your question could provide value to a wider audience by being framed in the context of JavaScript and JsLint only.  (I don't think the central question you are asking is specifically related to Backbone.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Backbone.Model.extend(new function(){
    var x;
    this.value = "";
    this.func = function() {
        return x;
    };
});
```

Can be replaced with:

```
Backbone.Model.extend(function(){
    var x;

    return {
        value: "",

        func: function(){
            return x;
        }
    };
}())
```

Passes JSLint:

```
var Backbone;

Backbone.Model.extend((function () {
    "use strict";
    var x;

    return {
        value: "",

        func: function () {
            return x;
        }
    };
}()));
```

Comment: +1 from me. I full agree with you. I can only add that `new` has sense only if one need to have *constructor* function and probably some additional functions in *prototype*. The function will be shared between multiple instances. If on the other side one use new with anonymous function the result are not more as object like the last version of your code shows.

Comment: @WillShaver do you have any comments for how this is not a better or at least adequate method for "anonymous closures"?

Comment: Your answer is a good one - I was just hoping for more of an explanation for why 'new' should be avoided. Is it slower? Harder to read? I should have made my question of "why" more explicit. I hadn't considered returning an object literal as you did in this answer so thanks.

Comment: @WillShaver I don't personally think it's that bad, many of Crockford's rules are too opionated which is why jshint was created in the first place. As for why Crockford thinks it's bad, I don't know :P

Answer (score 2):

JSLint does **not** like doing `new anonFn`.

You can just do:

```
var StandardMethod = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('init');
    }
});

var LintOk = Backbone.Model.extend((function() {
    this.initialize = function() {
        console.log('init');
    };
    return this;
})());
var backbonefn = function() {
    this.initialize = function() {
        console.log('init');
    }
};
var LintHates = Backbone.Model.extend(new backbonefn);
var sm = new StandardMethod();
var lo = new LintOk();
var lh = new LintHates();​
```

Click on JSLint in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Ztycf/

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't like "new anonFn" but I'm wanting to know WHY. Is there something bad/wrong with the practice of new anon functions? Your method would have me put the model definition at the bottom of the file: even more confusing for other devs!

Comment: @firelore do you know what `new` does?

Comment: I'm thinking not well enough, so I'll remove the comment.

Answer (score 1):

It should work just fine, but crockford insists that you move the `call` of the self-invoking anonymous function inside the brackets were the function is defined.
For example, when i validate this code with jslint :

```
(function () { })();
```

it gives me this error :  *Move the invocation into the parens that contain the function.*
After I modify the code like this :

```
(function () { }());
```

it doesn't shout errors any more.

p.s. it really doesn't quite matter because the result is the same (of course I don't know about ie6<), but I always use the first method for self-invoking functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually run that code through jslint, the error mentioned is `Weird construction. Delete 'new'`. You don't need to specify `new function` when making anonymous functions in javascript.

Comment: `new function` makes a new `Object object`, not a function